# Can I load a default windows icon depending on different system from somewhere in the sytem files

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, icons, visual-c++-6

To be specific, I'm trying to write a windows program running on different windows systems, mostly XP and Win7 or Win8. I want it to load a system default icon from somewhere in the system files(which I don't know neither). Is that possible and how can I do that?

for example, a Text.txt file has its icon on windows XP, but a different icon on Win7. XP's recycle bin is different from Win7's recycle bin, too. So where can I load this system-dependent icon to my program?? ps I 'm using VC6, not .NET.

Comment: See e.g. [`SHGetStockIconInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762205%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (Not available on XP though, but it might give you hints what to look for.)

Answer (score 2):

If you want the icon for a particular type of file you can use `SHGetFileInfo`. For example, to get the icon for a text file:

```
SHFILEINFO sfi;
if (SHGetFileInfo(L".txt", FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, &sfi, sizeof(sfi), SHGFI_ICON | SHGFI_USEFILEATTRIBUTES ))
{
    // you now have the icon in sfi.hIcon
    // remember to destroy it when you are done with it
    DestroyIcon(sfi.hIcon);
}
```

The `SHGFI_ICON` flag indicates we want the large icon. You can add the `SHGFI_SMALLICON` flag to get the small icon.

`SHGFI_USEFILEATTRIBUTES` indicates that the filename we pass does not have to exist - the function will return the icon for the file class rather than for a specific existing file. If you want the icon for a particular file then pass the full pathname of the file to the `SHGetFileInfo` function and omit this flag.

If you want the icon for a system folder like recycle bin, this function can do that too. For example:

```
LPITEMIDLIST pidl;
if (SUCCEEDED(SHGetFolderLocation(0, CSIDL_BITBUCKET, 0, 0, &pidl)))
{
    SHFILEINFO sfi;
    if (SHGetFileInfo((LPCWSTR)pidl, 0, &sfi, sizeof(sfi), SHGFI_ICON | SHGFI_PIDL))
    {
        // you now have the icon in sfi.hIcon
        // remember to destroy it when you are done with it
        DestroyIcon(sfi.hIcon);
    }
    CoTaskMemFree(pidl);
}
```

See the documentation for [`SHGetFileInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762179%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for a full list of flags. And make sure you have called `OleInitialize()` or `CoInitializeEx()` to initialise COM before using these functions.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm new at programming. Do I use LoadIcon(NULL, LPCTSTR ) function to load sfi.hIcon to my program?? But how can I convert the second parameter?

Comment: No, `sfi.hIcon` is already loaded - you can use it in calls like `DrawIconEx()`.

Comment: Besides, I think my VC6 is too old so that when compiling, it says SHGetFolderLocation is undeclared identifier and also SHGetFileInfoA cannot convert parameter 1 from "const unsigned short *" to "const char *". Any solutions??

Comment: I don't want to draw it. I want to use it as my program's icon. I only know LoadIcon from resource. But don't know how to load this sfi.hIcon as my program's icon?

Comment: If you want to use it as your program's icon you should have said that in your question, since that's a completely different subject. You can't do this programatically - a program's icon is stored within the EXE file itself, in its resources.

Comment: Sorry I didn't describe the question very well. But recyble bin, or a text.txt will display different icon on different windows system, right? How can they do that?

Comment: They aren't executable programs. Most icons in Explorer are defined in the registry and this can point to different files on different systems (or the files that contain the icons are simply different in different versions of windows). But executable programs (.exe files) always contain their icon within them, and it can't change dynamically.

Comment: Alright then. So I'm thinking another options is to load two icons in resources, and display one of them depending on which system. Is that possible?

Comment: No it's not possible. A program doesn't load its own icon (unless it wants to display it itself). Explorer loads the icon. You can't control which icon Explorer loads. There's no way to do this except to have different versions of your program for different versions of the OS.

Comment: Really??? So I can't do: if system ==XP, load IconXP; if system == win7, load IconWin7 ?? It sounds possible..

Comment: What if I want my program just display one of the icons predefined in Explorer?? Say, my program displays a recycle bin icon? Is that possible?

Comment: No this isn't possible. I'm not going to say it again :)